# Active Admin uninitialized constant for class in /lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a custom class for ActiveAdmin to try and clean up code out of the controller override in my Resource file.

I have a class `creditcard.rb` in `/lib`:

```
class Creditcard

def initialize
    1
end

end
```

And I have this controller code in `subscriptions.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Subscription do

  controller do
    def update
    @test=Creditcard.new
```

Boom. `uninitialized constant Creditcard`. Anyone know how to use custom classes with ActiveAdmin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to add the lib directory to your autoload path if you're using Rails 3+.

You can do this by adding this line to your `application.rb` file inside of your `class Application < Rails::Application` definition:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```